# using dd command for folder, but deleted items don't seem deleted

Tags: osx, dd

here is the image[image]

I used dd command to create a new floppy.
First I tried it with a folder filled with naber.bin, test.bin, blabla.bin and boot.bin.

And then i deleted all except boot.bin. ls -a command shows there is no file, except boot.bin. I also deleted them in trash.

Then I used dd command for this folder and i am seeing, these files still exist.

How is that possible?
What is it? Is it about deleteting files for file systems, is it possible there are still binary files on the disk under this folder (if it is now i understand deleted files recovery programs ^_^ )?

Comment: and also secure erasing this folder doesnt work , i still see deleted files name : 
how could it be possible

Comment: How did you "use[d] dd command for this folder"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post output of sw_vers + the exact commands you use for your dd.

Also the output of - file aramok - which will fail if aramok is a file or directory (see below).

Posting an image is difficult to read. Actual commands are better.

It appears you're attempting to somehow write (dd) to a floppy with no formatting. Meaning your trying to dd either a file or a directory of files, which will likely fail.

Best way to accomplish what it appears you're trying to accomplish, is to use "Disk Utility", as it appears you're using a Mac. First format your floppy as single partition + MSDOS disk. Then drag + drop files you wish onto your formatted floppy.

To use dd to accomplish this is complex. You'd have to create a binary file, like a .iso file which is the exact the same size (in bits) as your floppy with all your files contained in the .iso file.